# CSS background shortcut

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

Is it possible to program CSS's `background` with raw values for both its `background` `background-color` shorthand? I.e., `body { background: white rgb(0, 255, 127) }`

I was able to use a clever hack, which was use a 1x1 white pixel, `background.png`, i.e., `body { background: url("background.png") rgb(0, 255, 127) }`

And I think I can put a raw `data:image/png;base64`, but when I uploaded the same 1x1 white pixel online, it generated like a 500 character code, which seems insane for a 1x1 white pixel.

Is there another method to achieve the same effect using just `background`? The effect being a white foreground and green background. Demo live at ([zaydek.github.io](http://zaydek.github.io)). To see effect, drag up and down on the webpage.

I know I can do so with `divs`, etc., but I am curious about just CSS properties on one element, i.e., `body` or a combination of `html` and `body`. Thanks.

Comment: Your demo only flickers green for a second for me so hard to tell what you are asking about.

Comment: You're right! Sorry, drag up and down to see what I mean. Corrected OP

Comment: I was able to get several dozen charcters with http://b64.io

Answer (score 0):

Found a viable anwser at [http://proger.i-forge.net/Компьютер/[20121112]%20The%20smallest%20transparent%20pixel.html](http://proger.i-forge.net/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80/[20121112]%20The%20smallest%20transparent%20pixel.html)

> The winner is 1-color GIF – 35 bytes. Data URI for white 1×1 image:
>
> `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=`